# how to exchange messages between two java applications via Spring JMS?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I have two simple Spring applications acting as sender and receiver (code below). Although following [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) I can send and receive the messages within the same application I could not find how to make it work between two separate applications. I assume there should be a way of configuring both applications to find each other on the network. How can I do that using Spring configuration?

**Sender application**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application 
{

static String mailboxDestination = "mailbox-destination";


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Clean out any ActiveMQ data from a previous run
    FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));

    // Launch the application
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    // Send a message
    MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage("ping!");
        }
    };
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
    System.out.println("Sending a new message.");
    jmsTemplate.send(mailboxDestination, messageCreator);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Receiver application**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application 
{

static String mailboxDestination = "mailbox-destination";

@Bean
Receiver receiver() {
    return new Receiver();
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter adapter(Receiver receiver) {
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener
            = new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
    messageListener.setDefaultListenerMethod("receiveMessage");
    return messageListener;
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(MessageListenerAdapter messageListener,
                                         ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setDestinationName(mailboxDestination);
    return container;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Clean out any ActiveMQ data from a previous run
    FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));

    // Launch the application
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);



}

}



public class Receiver 
{

@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

/**
 * When you receive a message, print it out, then shut down the application.
 * Finally, clean up any ActiveMQ server stuff.
 */
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    context.close();
    FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually "NO". Since you use JMS aplications don't have to find `each other on the network`.

It is a JMS, so they both just should know a `Broker` URL to connect, as for sending part as well as for receiving.

You just need to configure `application.properties` correctly:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://192.168.1.210:9876
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=secret
```

And continue to use the same `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on both sides.

Comment: I see. So should I create the `application.properties` file and add these properties. I am using the embedded ActiveMQ provided by spring tool suite, so not sure how to configure these properties.

Comment: Of course you have to have a `real` ActiveMQ Broker to exchange messages through the network.